Malihu - mCustomScrollBar axis:"yx" doesn't work perfect for jquery 3.5.0+
The axis: "yx" didn't align well for jquery version 3.5.0, 3.6.0+ but it works fine for jquery version 3.4.1 and below. How can we make it compatible with jquery 3.5.0 and 3.6.0+ versions
            $(".wrapper").mCustomScrollbar({
            theme: "minimal-dark",
            scrollbarPosition: "outside",
            scrollInertia: 50, 
            scrollButtons: { 
                enable: true,
            },
            keyboard: { 
                enable: true, 
                scrollAmount: 6, 
            },
            axis: "yx",
            callbacks: {
                // onUpdate: function() { },
                
                // onScroll: function() {},

                whileScrolling: function () {
                    // let topOffset = Math.abs(this.mcs.top);
                }
            }
        }); 

